# Reading individual JSON events using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a file with several JSON objects, each of which may contain other objects and arrays.

I would like to deserialize this, preferably using the Jackson library, into a data structure that maintains top-level object separation, e.g. an array or a list of Java `HashMap<String, String>` objects, where each `HashMap` will contain the data of a single top-level JSON object from the file.

From what I have seen, you can't get a `HashMap<String, String>` from Jackson, so I have to put up with a `HashMap<String, Object>`:

```
List<HashMap<String,Object>> values = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)), new TypeReference<List<HashMap<String, Object>>>() {});
```

The deserialization above works as expected, however I get all the file data and a not a single JSON object's data, as I would like.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What's a simple JSON example that matches what you're trying to use?

Answer (score 3):

After quite a bit of effort, here is a simple approach that seems to work:

```
Reader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

int readEvents = 0;

JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

JsonParser parser = factory.createJsonParser(inputReader);

JsonToken token = null;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap<String,Object> attributes = null;
ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> matchedEvents = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

try
{
    while ((token=parser.nextToken()) != null)
    {
        if (token == JsonToken.START_OBJECT)
        {
            readEvents++;
            attributes = mapper.readValue(parser,
                     new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {});
            if (attributes != null)
            {
                matchedEvents.add(attributes);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Read " + readEvents + " events");
```

Each of the `HashMap<String, Object>` objects placed in the above `ArrayList` corresponds to a single (top-level) JSON event.

The `readValue()` methods apparently do not return a `Map(String, String)` object.

Comment: "The readValue() methods apparently do not return a Map(String, String) object."  -- The readValue methods will indeed return Map<String, String> instances, if both the input JSON and the target type specified to readValue provide that structure.  I'm guessing your JSON structure is not a map of string/string, but rather a map of string/object, and you're trying to convince Jackson that it's a map of string/string, but it's not.